# Flask-sqlalchemy: I have 4 tables, how to join them to find the data I want

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a project, and I have four tables in my database – User, Topic, Question, Answer.
Every user can follow many topics and questions, one topic has many followers, one question has many followers and answers. besides, one question can be related to more than one topic.

Now I want to **find out all the answers under the topics I'm following and I want all the answers ordered by timestamp**. How can I figure this out with flask-sqlalchemy ? I have been working all day on it but can not find out the solution.

Here is the code:

```
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    followers = db.relationship('User',
                                secondary=questions_users,
                                backref=db.backref('questions_following', lazy='dynamic'),
                                lazy='dynamic')
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='question', lazy='dynamic')

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    questions_asked = db.relationship('Question',backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

questions_users = db.Table('questions_users',
    db.Column('question_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id')),
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')))

class Topic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    followers = db.relationship('User',
                          secondary=topics_users,
                          backref=db.backref('topics', lazy='dynamic'),
                          lazy='dynamic')
    questions = db.relationship('Question',
                            secondary=topics_questions,
                            backref=db.backref('topics', lazy='dynamic'),
                            lazy='dynamic')

class Answer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow, index=True)
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))



topics_users = db.Table('topics_users',
    db.Column('topic_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topics.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')))


topics_questions = db.Table('topics_questions',
    db.Column('topic_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topics.id')),
    db.Column('question_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, then you could simply [join along Answer's question - topics - followers](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join), filter and order:

```
In [7]: db.session.query(Answer).\
   ...:     join('question', 'topics', 'followers').\
   ...:     filter(User.id == 1).\
   ...:     order_by(Answer.timestamp)
```

Due to the many to many relationships an answer might be included many times in the result set, but since SQLAlchemy sort of dedupes single entity queries, this is not a visible problem. The query could be written using EXISTS as well:

```
In [11]: db.session.query(Answer).\
    ...:     join(Question).\
    ...:     filter(Question.topics.any(
    ...:         Topic.followers.any(
    ...:             User.id == 1))).\
    ...:     order_by(Answer.timestamp)
```

Comment: I made a test and the second method is correct. Thanks very much, especially for the link to 'Query API'